# Python transition matrix

Tags: python, transition

I have a list looking like this:

[2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2]

What I want is a transition matrix which shows me the sequence like:

- How often is a 1 followed by a 1
- How often is a 1 followed by a 2
- How often is a 1 followed by a 3
- How often is a 2 followed by a 1
- How often is a 2 followed by a 2
- How often is a 2 followed by a 3

and so on...

((0,2,1), (1,2,1), (2,0,0))

Is there a premade module go get this?

Comment: What is the second tuple?

Comment: How often is a 2 followed by a 1
How often is a 2 followed by a 2
How often is a 2 followed by a 3

Comment: But a 2 is followed by a 1 one time in your list. Why is your tuple then (0, 2, 1)? Shouldn't it be (1,2,1)? (assuming the tuple is structured like `(number of occurrences, first number, number following the first number)`)

Comment: @Kevin I think ahrf meant  2 followed by 1 from left to right. the sequence "1,2" repeats twice

Comment: Is this a transition matrix in the same sense as a markov chain? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix If so, perhaps you should make that clear.

Comment: @AndrewJaffe I don't think it is. A stochastic matrix has probabilities, and rows/columns/both sums to one

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't know if there's a module, but I'd go with this code, which is easily generalizeable:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter
a = [2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2]
b = np.zeros((3,3))
for (x,y), c in Counter(zip(a, a[1:])).iteritems():
    b[x-1,y-1] = c
print b
array([[ 0.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  0.,  0.]])
```

With no numpy installed:

```
b = [[0 for _ in xrange(3)] for _ in xrange(3)]
for (x,y), c in Counter(zip(a, a[1:])).iteritems():
    b[x-1][y-1] = c

print b
[[0, 2, 1], [1, 2, 1], [2, 0, 0]]
```

A few details of what's going on, if needed:

1. `zip(a, a[1:])` gets all the pairs of consecutive numbers.
2. `Counter` counts how many times each pair appears
3. The for loop simple converts the dictionary `Counter` produces into the matrix / list of lists you requested

Comment: What if we don't have `numpy` installed? What alternative is there in out-of-the-box Python?

Comment: @Kevin: `[[0 for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]`

Comment: @Kevin updated with a no numpy version. But I really do recommend numpy. If there's a module-solution like you originally requested - it probably involves it.

Comment: I'm using python 3.x might that be the reason i get the error: 'Counter' object has no attribute 'iteritems'?

Comment: @ahrf: yep.  You can use `.items()` instead.  (And `range` instead of `xrange`, and fix the `print`s, of course.)

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you, works pretty well! Especially for the detailed explanation of the code!!